# Subset returned by queryForList is incorrect,but executed in SQL Developer it's OK

Tags: java, subset, jdbctemplate

Subset returned in DAO class:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> agreements = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sqlForDataQuery.toString(), paramsForList.toArray());
```

It expected to be sorted,but in debug mode application returns incorrect subset - it's not sorted.

From other hand,if to execute `sqlForDataQuery` with all `paramsForList` in Oracle Sql Developer, that expected sorted correct subset returned.

`sqlForDataQuery` runtime value:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT t1.*, ROWNUM rn FROM (SELECT /*+ CHOOSE */ DISTINCT a.avtalenavn, a.kunde_id, a.aktivdato, a.bank_id, a.avtalestatus_id, a.produkt_id, a.avtale_id, p.navn, k.foretaksnr, k.navn AS KUNDENAVN FROM es.avtale a, es.avtale_konto ak, es.kunde k, es.produkt p WHERE a.bank_id = ? AND ak.avtale_id = a.avtale_id AND a.kunde_id = k.kunde_id AND UPPER(a.avtalenavn) LIKE UPPER(('%' || ? || '%')) AND a.produkt_id = p.produkt_id ORDER BY ? ) t1 ) WHERE rn BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

`paramsForList` runtime value:

```
4210, a, AVTALE_ID, 1, 5
```

Looks like query executed not correctly,but no Exception thrown.

Have you any idea of problem scope?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the sql that the queryForList generates?

Comment: @Liviu T  - I've posted values of query and its parameters,that I got in debug

Comment: @Liviu T  I tries - ORDER BY part of query with DESC or default value(ASC) doesn't return sorted subset

Comment: I don't think you can pass a paramater to be used as a order column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-databases/2097/PreparedStatement-order-by)

Short story: you can't use parameters as columns for ordering in a PreparedStatement and jdbcTemplate uses prepared statements under the hood.

Comment: it's interesting, I should investigate,thank you for assistance